# Can anyone help me fix this Font issue

Tags: wine

[image]
I have a font problem in LOL runing in lutris in Ubuntu 16.04 all other words are readable except the shop, settings and chat. Any help would be great. thanks

Comment: did you install windows core fonts?

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: I installed all fonts in winetricks. no change

Comment: which version of wine? I use 2.0.1 with a XP prefix

Comment: 1.8 with XP, everything is running fine except this font problem. its only in game. the client looks fine.

Comment: hmmm, did you download LOL or copy a directory from win? I think you are missing a font but I don't know which

Comment: I am running it through Lutris, so it auto installs with all the libraries

Comment: I found the solution here:  https://forums.lutris.net/t/weird-font-ingame-for-league-of-legends/521/6